# How to Rotate a vector along another vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics, mathematical-physics, rotations

I want to rotate a vector e.g $V = Ai + Bj + Ck$ along an another vector 
$U = xi + yj + zk$. The angle between $U$ and $V$ is $\theta$.

How can I do that and how do I know the new value of $A$, $B$, $C$ along the direction of $U$.

Thanks in advance.

Bk

Comment: What do you mean by "rotate along"?

Comment: Take a look at Rodrigues' formula - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

Comment: by "rotate along" i mean in the same direction

Comment: @Bikash Are you interested in a general approach or you are looking for a made up formula?

Comment: @gimusi..A general approach is better. Actually, I am planning to write a code for it.

Comment: @Bikash In general it can be obtained by standar rotation matrix by means of a chenge of basis, it requires some knowledge in linear algebra, if you are interested I can give some indication by this way

Comment: Sure...I have some basic knowledge of linear algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a general approach we can proceed as follow

1. Consider an orthogonal basis with $v_1=U$, $v_2=V-\frac{V\cdot U}{U\cdot U}U$ and $v_3=v_1\times v_2$
2. In this basis the vector $V$ is $V_B=(|V|\cos \theta,|V|\sin \theta, 0)$
3. Find the rotated $W_B$ by standard rotation matrix $R_B$ that is $W_B=R_BV_B$
4. Return to the standard basis by $W=MW_B$ where $M$ is the matrix for the change of basis from the new basis to the standard basis that is $M=[v_1\quad  v_2\quad v_3]$
5. We can also obtain the expression for the rotation matrix in the standard basis indeed

$$W_B=R_BV_B\iff M^{-1}W=R_BM^{-1}V\iff W=MR_BM^{-1}V \quad R=MR_BM^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rotation matrix if you want to rotate a vector 'around' the direction $n$ (with $|n|=1$) by $\theta$:
$$R_{kl}=\cos(\theta)\delta_{kl}+n_kn_l(1-\cos(\theta))+\sum_{m}\epsilon_{kml}n_m\sin(\theta)$$