# Where does this formular for rotating a vector in 3D space around another 3D vector comes from?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, rotations, robotics

I found this formular: $\mathbf{R}_{\vec{n}}(\alpha)\vec{x}=\vec{n}(\vec{n}\cdot\vec{x})+\cos(\alpha)(\vec{n}\times\vec{x})\times\vec{n}+\sin(\alpha)(\vec{n}\times\vec{x})$ here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drehmatrix. This operation rotates $\vec{x}$ (which is a 3D vector) around $\vec{n}$ (a 3D vector too with $|\vec{n}|=1$) by the angle $\alpha$.

Aplying this operation is no problem it just works like a charme. The problem comes when i need to tell a text book with this formular. I coulnd't find it written down anywhere.

Googling a bit i found this: [How to Rotate a vector along another vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694361/how-to-rotate-a-vector-along-another-vector) (second answer) or again this: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drehmatrix
where it states some kind of a more general rule (n-dimensional?), but i do not know how to deduce the 3D formular from that.

Does anyone of you guys saw this operation written down in a text book, a german one whould be prefered.

Comment: Why don't you just prove that the formula is correct, and then you will not need a textbook?

Comment: The derivation of Rodrigues' rotation formula here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula may be helpful for you (or maybe not:). And, sorry, that's English, but maybe there's a German translation page. By the way, when you say "it just works like a charm", I'm inferring you're programming it. I've programmed lots of 3D image rotations, using the usual rotation matrices, and also quaternions, etc. And I've also found Rodrigues' formula the most straightforward for application purposes. So once you're happy that you understand the derivation, I'd continue using it.

Comment: Do you exclusively want a textbook reference, or would a derivation of the formula suffice?

Comment: @uniquesolution: i already did a validation and i mentioned that i'm applying the formular successesfully. Thanks for the hint John, i'll use Mauricio's derivation. Yes Spencer, a derivation would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just another flavor of the Rodrigues rotation  formula: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula which can be found in german text books for sure.

Proof:

Rodrigues formula is:

$$v' = \cos(\theta) v + \sin(\theta) n \times v + (1 - \cos(\theta)) n (n \cdot v)$$

which can also be written as:

$$v' = n (n \cdot v) + \cos(\theta) (v - n (n \cdot v))+ \sin(\theta) n \times v$$

Using the following identity:

$$a \times (b \times c) = b (a \cdot c) - c (a \cdot b)$$

we find that:

$$(n \times v) \times n = - n \times (n \times v)$$
$$(n \times v) \times n = - n (n \cdot v) + v (n \cdot n)$$

Using the fact that $\|n\| = 1$:

$$(n \times v) \times n =  v - n (n \cdot v)$$

Replacing that in the Rodrigues formula we get:

$$v' = n (n \cdot v) + \cos(\theta) (n \times v) \times n + \sin(\theta) n \times v$$

Which is what you are using.